# Selenium/python click to open multiple rows

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to scrape the data in a bunch of rows. I am able to expand an individual row using the following:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="7858101"]'))).click()
```

The problem is each row has a different id. They have common class name so I have also tried:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'course-row normal faculty-BU active'))).click()
```

I have attached a few rows below Any suggestions on how I can fix this

```
<tr id="7858101" class="course-row normal faculty-BU active" data-cid="7858101" data-cc="ACTG1P01" data-year="2021" data-session="FW" data-type="UG" data-subtype="UG" data-level="Year1" data-fn2_notes="BB" data-duration="2" data-class_type="ASY" data-course_section="1" data-days="       " data-class_time="" data-room1="ASYNC" data-room2="" data-location="ASYNC" data-location_desc="" data-instructor="Zhang, Xia (Celine)" data-msg="0" data-main_flag="1" data-secondary_type="E" data-startdate="1631073600" data-enddate="1638853200" data-faculty_code="BU" data-faculty_desc="Goodman School of Business">
            
            <td class="arrow"><span class="fa fa-angle-down"></span></td>
            <td class="course-code">ACTG 1P01 </td>
            <td class="title"><a href="#" data-cc="ACTG1P01" data-cid="7858101">Introduction to Financial Accounting</a> <div class="details-loader" style="display: none;"><span class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-fw"></span></div></td>
            
            <td class="duration">D2</td>
            

            <td class="days">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="time">&nbsp;</td>
            
<!--            <td class="start" data-sort-value="1631073600">Sep 08, 2021</td> -->
<!--            <td class="end" data-sort-value="1638853200">Dec 07, 2021</td> -->

            <td class="type">ASY</td>
            <td class="data"><div style="" class="course-details-data"> 
    <div class="description">
        
        <h3>Introduction to Financial Accounting</h3>
        
                <p class="page-intro">Fundamental concepts of financial accounting as related to the balance sheet, income statement and statement of cash flows. Understanding the accounting cycle and routine transactions. Integrates both theoretical and practical application of accounting concepts.</p>
                
                <p><strong>Format:</strong> Lectures, discussion, 3 hours per week.</p>
                
                <p><strong>Restrictions:</strong> open to BAcc majors.</p>
                
                
                
                <p><strong>Exclusions:</strong> Completion of this course will replace previous assigned grade and credit obtained in ACTG 1P11, 1P91 and 2P51.</p>
                
                
                <p><strong>Notes:</strong> Open to Bachelor of Accounting majors.   </p>
                
    </div>
    
    <div class="vitals">
        
        <ul>
            
                        <li><strong>Duration:</strong> Sep 08, 2021 to Dec 07, 2021</li>
                        
                        
                        
                        <li>
                <strong>Location:</strong> ASYNC                            </li>
            
            
                        <li><strong>Instructor:</strong> Zhang, Xia (Celine)</li>
                        
                        <li><strong>Section:</strong> 1</li>
                        
                        
            
        </ul>
        
    </div>
    
    <hr>
    
        
    
    </div>
</td>
            
        </tr>



<tr id="3724102" class="course-row normal faculty-BU active" data-cid="3724102" data-cc="ACTG1P01" data-year="2021" data-session="FW" data-type="UG" data-subtype="UG" data-level="Year1" data-fn2_notes="BB" data-duration="2" data-class_type="LEC" data-course_section="2" data-days=" M  R  " data-class_time="1100-1230" data-room1="GSB306" data-room2="" data-location="GSB306" data-location_desc="" data-instructor="Zhang, Xia (Celine)" data-msg="0" data-main_flag="1" data-secondary_type="E" data-startdate="1631073600" data-enddate="1638853200" data-faculty_code="BU" data-faculty_desc="Goodman School of Business">
            
            <td class="arrow"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span></td>
            <td class="course-code">ACTG 1P01 </td>
            <td class="title"><a href="#" data-cc="ACTG1P01" data-cid="3724102">Introduction to Financial Accounting</a> <div class="details-loader"><span class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-fw"></span></div></td>
            
            <td class="duration">D2</td>
            

            <td class="days">&nbsp; 
    <table class="coursecal">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="">S</th>
                <th class="active">M</th>
                <th class="">T</th>
                <th class="">W</th>
                <th class="active">T</th>
                <th class="">F</th>
                <th class="">S</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                
                <td class="weekend "></td>
                <td class="active"></td>
                <td class=""></td>
                <td class=""></td>
                <td class="active"></td>
                <td class=""></td>
                <td class="weekend "></td>
    
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    
    </td>
            <td class="time">1100-1230</td>
            
<!--            <td class="start" data-sort-value="1631073600">Sep 08, 2021</td> -->
<!--            <td class="end" data-sort-value="1638853200">Dec 07, 2021</td> -->

            <td class="type">LEC</td>
            <td class="data"></td>
            
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: screenshot of DOM tree]

Are almost there...
You can retrieve a **list** of all the relevant web elements with the use of `driver.find_elements` method and then to iterate over each element in the list clicking on it.
Since `course-row normal faculty-BU active` is actually several class names, not a single class name, you should use XPath or CSS Selector there.
Also it's recommended to use `visibility_of_element_located` expected condition here, not `presence_of_elements_located` since the former condition is fulfilled even when the web element is not finally rendered on the page while `visibility_of_element_located` expected condition waits for more mature state of the web element

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//tr[@class = "course-row normal faculty-BU active"]')))
time.sleep(0.4) #short delay added to make ALL the elements loaded
elements = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//tr[@class = "course-row normal faculty-BU active"]')
for element in elements:
    element.click()
    #scrape the data you need here etc
```

Comment: I received this error message: selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
I tried adding time.sleep in between commands but the AJAX still doesn't load completely

Comment: OK, please try using `presence_of_elements_located` instead of `visibility_of_element_located`

Comment: Does it work with `presence_of_elements_located`?

Comment: Hi, it still shows the same error, the same goes for the other solution posted. It will only identify a hardcoded id value. The rows are in a tbody tag so I have tried adding tbody as well to the Xpath with same error.

Answer (score 0):

As the `id` attributes of the `<tr>` have dynamic value to identify all the `<tr>`s and click on each of them you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) and you need to construct a dynamic [locator strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver) as follows:

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "tr.course-row.normal.faculty-BU.active[data-faculty_desc='Goodman School of Business'] a[data-cc][data-cid]")))
  for element in elements:
      element.click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//tr[@class='course-row normal faculty-BU active' and @data-faculty_desc='Goodman School of Business']//a[@data-cc and @data-cid]")))
  for element in elements:
      element.click()
  ```